# Using WP_UnitTestCase scaffolding in PHPStrom with composer

Tags: wordpress, phpunit, composer-php, phpstorm

I configured WP_UnitTestCase and the wp_cli and PHPUnit with composer in PHPStorm. I had an issue where it couldn’t find/use my WP DB username and password to create the DB so I created it manually in the terminal. (was this a mistake?)  install-wp-tests.sh the installed, I was able to run some test did a bit of development and then shutdown my machine.

The next day, I started up my machine and attempted to continue where I left off. However PHPunit (should I be calling this WP_UnitTestCase instead?) Failed to run with the following errors.

> Warning: require_once(/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php): failed to >open stream: No such file or directory in /thefullpathtowordpressprojectd/wp->content/plugins/myplugin/tests/bootstrap.php on line 8

Well `/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/` doesn’t exist

So I look into the install-wp-tests.sh and its installing itself to a tmp directory…okay?!  (So ok I  did notice that phpunit said Installing when I ran my tests the night before… so it reinstalls itself for every test!?)

Then I re-run ‘install-wp-tests.sh’, it fails when attempting to create the ‘wordpress-tests’ db since it already exist but I can now run tests again.

My question is even if the scaffolding/ WP_UnitTestCase reinstalls itself every time I run phpunit in the directory of my plugin folder where my phpunit.xml is. What do I have to change in the ‘install-wp-tests.sh’ or phpunit.xml so I don't have to manually reinstall for an existing project, how to clear the require_once error for the tmp empty directory?

Should I have to reinstall it everytime I reopen my project?

my install-we-test.sh is unchanged, but here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
   echo "usage: $0 <db-name> <db-user> <db-pass> [db-host] [wp-version]"
   exit 1
fi

DB_NAME=$1
DB_USER=$2
DB_PASS=$3
DB_HOST=${4-localhost}
WP_VERSION=${5-latest}

WP_TESTS_DIR=${WP_TESTS_DIR-/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib}
WP_CORE_DIR=${WP_CORE_DIR-/tmp/wordpress/}

set -ex

download() {
    if [ `which curl` ]; then
        curl -s "$1" > "$2";
    elif [ `which wget` ]; then
        wget -nv -O "$2" "$1"
    fi
}

install_wp() {

   if [ -d $WP_CORE_DIR ]; then
      return;
   fi

   mkdir -p $WP_CORE_DIR

   if [ $WP_VERSION == 'latest' ]; then
      local ARCHIVE_NAME='latest'
   else
      local ARCHIVE_NAME="wordpress-$WP_VERSION"
   fi

   download https://wordpress.org/${ARCHIVE_NAME}.tar.gz  /tmp/wordpress.tar.gz
   tar --strip-components=1 -zxmf /tmp/wordpress.tar.gz -C $WP_CORE_DIR

   download https://raw.github.com/markoheijnen/wp-mysqli/master/db.php $WP_CORE_DIR/wp-content/db.php
}

install_test_suite() {
   # portable in-place argument for both GNU sed and Mac OSX sed
   if [[ $(uname -s) == 'Darwin' ]]; then
      local ioption='-i .bak'
   else
      local ioption='-i'
   fi

   # set up testing suite if it doesn't yet exist
   if [ ! -d $WP_TESTS_DIR ]; then
      # set up testing suite
      mkdir -p $WP_TESTS_DIR
      svn co --quiet http://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/ $WP_TESTS_DIR/includes
   fi

   cd $WP_TESTS_DIR

   if [ ! -f wp-tests-config.php ]; then
      download https://develop.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-tests-config-sample.php "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
      sed $ioption "s:dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/src/':'$WP_CORE_DIR':" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
      sed $ioption "s/youremptytestdbnamehere/$DB_NAME/" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
      sed $ioption "s/yourusernamehere/$DB_USER/" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
      sed $ioption "s/yourpasswordhere/$DB_PASS/" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
      sed $ioption "s|localhost|${DB_HOST}|" "$WP_TESTS_DIR"/wp-tests-config.php
   fi

}

install_db() {
   # parse DB_HOST for port or socket references
   local PARTS=(${DB_HOST//\:/ })
   local DB_HOSTNAME=${PARTS[0]};
   local DB_SOCK_OR_PORT=${PARTS[1]};
   local EXTRA=""

   if ! [ -z $DB_HOSTNAME ] ; then
      if [ $(echo $DB_SOCK_OR_PORT | grep -e '^[0-9]\{1,\}$') ]; then
         EXTRA=" --host=$DB_HOSTNAME --port=$DB_SOCK_OR_PORT --protocol=tcp"
      elif ! [ -z $DB_SOCK_OR_PORT ] ; then
         EXTRA=" --socket=$DB_SOCK_OR_PORT"
      elif ! [ -z $DB_HOSTNAME ] ; then
         EXTRA=" --host=$DB_HOSTNAME --protocol=tcp"
      fi
   fi

   # create database
   mysqladmin create $DB_NAME --user="$DB_USER" --password="$DB_PASS"$EXTRA
}

install_wp
install_test_suite
install_db
```

and my phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite>
            <directory prefix="test-" suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Well... i created an alias to run the install script with the parameter of the already created test db.